# Multiple Selection table, without selection of mouse dragging

Tags: qt, qtableview, qabstractitemview, qitemselectionmodel

I would like to have `QAbstractItemView` that will allow multi-selection of items only with `ctrl` button toggle. I can't use `QAbstractItemView::ExtandedSelection` because it also allow multiple items selection by dragging the mouse over them.

Answer (score 3):

I assume you are using a `QTableView`
You can override the `QTableView` and then use `mouseMoveEvent` cleverly to ensure that user can't make multiple selections by dragging!

If user enters into `mouseMoveEvent` with the left mouse button pressed, you can choose to eat the event without passing it to the `QTableView` that will remove the possibility of multiple selection.

e.g.

```
void
TableView::mouseMoveEvent( QMouseEvent * inEvent )
{
// Deliberately commented to not to pass this event to parent to avoid multiple selection
// QTableView( inEvent );
inEvent->accept();
}
```

This might work for you, you may also have to be careful in the `mouseMoveEvent`, when you do above to mousePressEvent you have to do the same for `mouseReleaseEvent` as well.

Though this is just a theory , but is should work!